# How can we write a simple code that generates a random but excluding the user's input in python

Tags: python

I am making a rock paper scissors game and for that I want the computer to choose a random choice excluding the player's choice so if a player chooses rock then it should choose randomly between paper and scissors. Can anyone help me out?

This is my code:

```
symbols = [rock,paper,scissors]
player_input = input("Please type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors. ")
player_choice = int(player_input) - 1
```

Comment: The trivial and obvious solution is to loop until you get a random value which is distinct from the one the user selected. It's not hard to create a `set` with the alternatives, remove the member which was already taken, and pass the remainder to the randomization function. Did you search before asking?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code. The first choice will be removed from the list of choices.

```
c = [1,2,3] # 3 choices
a = random.choice(c) # pick the first (e.g. by input player)
print (a) 
c.remove(a) # remove it from the list of choices
b = random.choice(c) # pick the second (e.g. by computer)
print (b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along this line (assuming I am continuing from your code above):

```
import random
remaining_symbol = symbols
remaining_symbol.pop(player_choice)
result = remaining_symbol[random.randint(0, len(remaining_symbol))]
print(result) #this should give you the answer
```

I have not tested this code but it should be along this idea.

Comment: It bears pointing out that this permanently modifies `symbols`. Probably make sure it's a copy of the authoritative variable; and the answer should probably explain this in more detail.

Comment: The indirection via `randint` is noisy and unnecessarily complex. You want `random.choice(symbols)`

Comment: The code assigns the user's choice to `remining_symbol`; the random function should pick from the actually remaining `symbols`, and the variable probably renamed.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for pointing that out. edited the code so that it creates a duplicate before using the pop..

Comment: The argument to `pop` should be zero-based (subtract one).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
from random import choice

symbols = ["rock","paper","scissors"]

try:    
    player_input = int(input("Please type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors. ")) - 1
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    print("Not a valid input")
else:
    symbols_two = [thing for thing in symbols if thing != symbols[player_input]]

    print('random answer: {}'.format(choice(symbols_two)))
```

- this code is not tested for errors